# VBA Function to return cell reference

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I currently have a workbook with alot of references to another workbook that gets updated hourly. I have macros that uses the find and replace function to change the cell references to another set of data. The problem is the find and replace iterates over all the cells which takes to much time. My idea is to define a function that returns a new cell ref however I have been unsuccesfull in making it work any help would be appreciated. This is what I have so far

```
 Public Function test(cel) As Range
Dim celvar As Integer
celvar = cel
var1 = "=('\\server\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\[workbook.xlsx]"
var2 = Range("I2").Value
var3 = "'!$B"
var4 = ")"
test = var1 & var2 & var3 & celvar & var4
End Function
```

the I would call the function in the target cell like so
=test(151) and have it return 
=('\server\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4[workbook.xlsx]sheet'!$B153)

unforfunatly it returnes either #Ref or #Value

Comment: what do you mean by "change the cell references to another set of data"? Also, is your issue caused by the brackets around the whole reference string? I don't think those are necessary.

Comment: for instance I would like to dynamically change ('\server\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4[workbook.xlsx]sheet'!$B153) to

Comment: for instance j153 instead

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve this is difficult, but I can see your function is set to return a range, when your concatenate is creating a string. I'd also specify the type of variable your expecting, which is an integer based on your use of cel, so make sure you're sending an integer to the function, finally make sure you're setting the cell.formula to your test string, not cell.value

```
Public Function test(cel as integer) As string
var1 = "=('\\server\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\[workbook.xlsx]"
var2 = Range("I2").Value
var3 = "'!$B"
var4 = ")"
test = var1 & var2 & var3 & cel & var4
End Function
```

However, as you're using the function as an in-cell function, I expect this will just treat the output as a string, not a formula, so you may need to also add something to evaluate the cell - perhaps cellnexttothisone.formula = thiscell.value

Comment: yes it is an in cell function. the basic idea is I have the global variables var 1-4 that change frequently due to other macro's the idea is to dynamically change the cell ref of var 2 and 3 thus updating all the cell ref instantly. instead of using find and replace which is inconvienient as it takes 60 sec in which case the data is no longer current

Comment: You need a line in the function like currentrange=Application.Caller, to give you the current cell, then SheetName = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name to give you the current sheet. Then sheets(sheetname).range(currentrange).offset(1,0).formula = sheets(sheetname).range(currentrange).value. This will put the new string as a value in the original cell, and the formula version in the next cell, and this will pull the details from your external workbook.